# awk to print message based on data in the same file

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to print a message depending on diferent conditions using the data in the same `tab-delimeted file`. That is is the `---positive file---` was being used then the two conditions are meet and the variable `count` is 2 so that is printed. That seems to work but when I try to add  a condition for the `---negative file---`, that is where the two conditions are not meet `^ unexpected newline or end of string` is the error. I thought the syntax was correct but I am missing something.  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '$1=="Control" && $2=="Present" {count++} END{print count " controls detected"} $1=="Control" && $2!="Present" {print "0 controls detected"}' file
```

**file  --- negative ---**

```
Control NoCall
Control NoCall
```

**file   ---positive file---**

```
Control Present
Control Present
```

**desired output --- negative file ---**

```
0 controls detected
```

**desired output   ---positive file ---**

```
2 controls detected
```

output after correction:

```
0 controls detected
0 controls detected
```

Comment: what is the real, actual content of your input `file`?

Comment: about 40 columns from a `.tsv`.... the two that I posted are in them just in a different order and are the two most important.  Thank you :).

Comment: sorry and 2800 rows in it :).

Comment: @Chris: Do you realize you have an unterminated `"` character in the example shown?

Comment: @Inian, thank you I didn't even notice.... after correcting I get the line `0 controls detected`... maybe missing an `END`?  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an un-terminated double-quote(`"`) in your example which could have caused a syntax violation. By the way instead of messing up multiple checks you could just have a ternary operator as below

```
awk -F'\t' ' $1=="Control" { ($2 == "Present")?(count++):(count=0);}END{print count" controls detected"}' file
```

The above logic seems to work for both your positive and negative files in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you place an additional pattern-action pair after the `END{...}` ? Thats confusing.
And it prints for each line fulfilling the pattern/condition. I don't think that's intended.

More likely, you want to print only at the END with a default for count

```
echo "Control\tno\nControl\tno\nControl\tno" |\
awk -F '\t' '
    $1=="Control" && $2=="Present" { count++ }
    END { print (count?count:0) " controls detected" }
    '
```